# Using Whiptail for bash script

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, whiptail

How can I exit the whiptail screen on the terminal and stop the script from running in between? Is there a combination that can be used to stop the script execution and exit, similar to Ctrl+c?

Comment: Have you tried the escape key?

Comment: Yes, it was the first thing I thought. It didnt work.

Comment: "Exit status is 0 if whiptail is exited by pressing the Yes or OK button, and 1 if the No or Cancel button is pressed. Otherwise, if errors occur inside whiptail or whiptail is exited by pressing the ESC key, the exit status is -1.
" This might be related to your OS / Shell / Whiptail version, although I believe they're all the same.

Comment: What I was intending to do is to press a key and exit the running script at any stage, just like we do it using Ctrl+c in bash. But I dont think this will be possible in whiptail, as everything works with boolean inputs in it.
What do you say?